# Check for camera on Android 1.6 (SDK 4)

Tags: android, camera, android-sdk-1.6

I have searched this server for the answer to this question but I haven't found one. I have only found [it for Android 2.0 (SDK 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368564/android-check-whether-camera-supports-auto-focus). So does anybody know how to find out whether there is a camera in Android 1.6 application? Can I check if the camera has autofocus.

Thank you for your answers,
saric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code to check if there is a camera ( https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html ):

```
/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
```

From the Android Compatibility page ( https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html ):

> Android 1.0 through 1.5 required a 2 megapixel camera with auto-focus.
>   However, with version 1.6, Android devices were permitted to omit the
>   auto-focus capability, though a (fixed-focus) camera was still
>   required. Some apps such as barcode scanners do not function as well
>   with cameras that do not auto-focus. To prevent users from having a
>   bad experience with those apps, existing apps that obtain permission
>   to use the Camera were assumed by default to require auto-focus. This
>   allowed Google Play to filter those apps from devices that lack
>   auto-focus.

Looking at the API here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#autoFocus%28android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback%29

It looks like they tell you to use a function that isn't present yet.

Unfortunately it may not be possible to check if the camera has auto-focus in Android 1.6.