# How to determine an android device whether supports "android.hardware.camera.autofocus"?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions

How to determine an android device whether supports "android.hardware.camera.autofocus"?

From where I can get a feature list supported by this android device?

I want to use feature in my app, but I don't know if the phone supports or not.

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    >
</uses-feature>
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="true"
    >
</uses-feature>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/4368564/1329126

Comment: Setting `required` to true will prevent phones that don't support auto-focus from installing your app. Is that what you want? If so, then determining if a phone supports auto-focus at runtime is moot.

Comment: @SankarV Is there any way to change my device to support autofocus but do not change my phone hardware?

Comment: @JasonRobinson Can I change my software to have an autofocus feature to cheat my app to install?

Comment: @VictorS No. If you don't require auto-focus for your app, then set `required` to false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can manage like

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
// Here if you get Camera Do you work Like

Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,MyFileContentProvider.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_RESULT);

 } else {
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Camera is not available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

also Add Require `Permission` of `Camera` to `AndroidManifest.xml` file